# How to parse an XML file and create objects using found values?

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I would like to parse an XML file using Java. I found some tutorials online but no one tells about parsing subtags and using them as objects' attributes.

I tried to use the code found [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_xml_parsers.htm).
But it doesn't show how to treat tags that are inside other tags. Let me show you an example:

```
<lotto>
            <cig>Z9E1CD9F58</cig>
            <strutturaProponente>
                <codiceFiscaleProp>00222010654</codiceFiscaleProp>
                <denominazione>COMUNE DI PERDIFUMO</denominazione>
            </strutturaProponente>
</lotto>
```

`lotto` is my main tag, which contains all the data I need. In my code, I created a class called in the same way. Its attributes are the same as the tags contained in the main one (cig, strutturaProponente,...).

I would like strutturaProponente to become a class. I don't know how to parse tags which are inside of tag `strutturaProponente` as well as the tag `cig`.
Thank you for your patience and consideration.

Comment: You could use an XmlPullParser and keep track of the current path yourself to know where you are in the file when handling elements.  When you start a tag, push the tag on the current path, and when you end a tag, pop it from the current path.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let me see if I understood. Would you like the representantion in code of XML, I believe that class would be like something this.

```java
public class Loto
{
    private String cig;

    public String getCig()
    {
        return cig;
    }

    public void setCig(String value){
       cig = value;
    }
}

public class StrutturaProponente
{
     private int codiceFiscaleProp;

     private string denominazione;

     public int getCodiceFiscaleProp()
     {
        return cig;
     }

     public void setCodiceFiscaleProp(int value){
       codiceFiscaleProp = value;
     }

    public String getDenominazione()
    {
        return denominazione;
    }

    public void setDenominazione(String value){
       denominazione = value;
    }
}
```

I hope have helped.

Comment: Yes the classes are like this, but I would like to parse values and use them as attributes of the objects.